# Unable to run a process on background

Tags: shell, io-redirection, solaris, background-process

I have used the following command to run the cp.sh script in the background.

```
nohup sh cp.sh < /dev/null & > /dev/null &
output: Invalid null command.
```

What would be the solution for this "Invalid null command" ?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have put a space between `& >`, which needs to be `&>`. This would redirect both STDOUT and STDERR to the file followed next.

So you need:

```
nohup sh cp.sh < /dev/null &> /dev/null &
```

If you shell does not support `&>`, use POSIX way to redirect both STDOUT and STDERR:

```
nohup sh cp.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Still showing "Invalid null command". note that, this works in linux. but i am using Solaris

Comment: got it .. if i use following command in soalris... it works...
    nohup sh cp.sh < /dev/null &

Comment: @Wasila That means you shell does not support STDOUT and STDERR redirection with `&>`..youa re probably using older `bash` or other arcane shell..no?

Comment: @Wasila Check my edits..

Answer (score 1):

The message is from a shell that complains about the syntax:

`& > /dev/null &`

is indeed a command line that contains `a command between two &` but this command does not have a command name but just a redirection for `stdout`.

BTW: For those who don't know yet: Since 12 years, Solaris allows to `nohup` an already running process by calling:

`nohup -p <pid>`

or

`nohup -g <pgid>`

This creates a file nohup.out and replaces the `stdout` file descriptor in the kernel by a file descriptor that refers to the file `nohup.out`.